# PHPWord - save file to specified path

Tags: phpword

```
 $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
 $section = $phpWord->addSection();
 $html = Storage::get('my-html-file.html');
 \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);
 $path = Storage::path('/my/directory/testingfile.docx');      
 $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
 $objWriter->save($path);
```

I need to be able to loop through html files I have and organize them into a file structure and save to my Laravel Storage path (which is `/storage/app`).

I'm not seeing any option in PHPWord to choose a path that you save the file in. It is just the temp directory.

How can I choose the directory and subdirectory to save a file?

I looked into the `save` method here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Writer/Word2007.php

and it just takes a file name and goes to the temp directory.